# Python - Limiting the Number of Threads while passing arguments

Tags: python, multithreading, arguments, parameter-passing, python-multithreading

I am trying to run some threads using a thread limiter to keep number of threads to 10. I had an example to use as guide but I need to pass in some arguments to the function when the calling the thread.  I am struggling with the passing of arguments.  I marked with ### the areas where I am not sure the syntax and where I think my problem is.

I am trying to use this [The right way to limit maximum number of threads running at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369724/the-right-way-to-limit-maximum-number-of-threads-running-at-once) as a guide.  Here is the sample code I am trying to follow.  My example is below that.  Any time I try to pass in all the arguments I get back `TypeError: __ init__() takes 1 to 6 arguments but 17 were passed` In my example below I cut the arguments down to 4 to make it easier to read but I have 17  arguments in my live code.  In example I keep the arguments down to `run, main_path, target_path, jiranum`   to keep reading easier

```
threadLimiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(maximumNumberOfThreads)

class MyThread(threading.Thread):

def run(self):  
    threadLimiter.acquire()
    try:
        self.Executemycode()
    finally:
        threadLimiter.release()

def Executemycode(self):
    print(" Hello World!") 
    # <your code here>
```

My code

```
import os
import sys
import threading

threadLimiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(10)

class MyThread(threading.Thread):

  def run(self):  ### I also tried (run, main_path, target_path, jiranum)
     threadLimiter.acquire()
     try:
       self.run_compare(run, main_path, target_path, jiranum) #### I also tried self
     finally:
       threadLimiter.release()

  def run_compare(run, main_path, target_path, jiranum):   #### ???
    os.chdir(target_path)
    os.system(main_path + ', ' + target_path + ',' + jiranum + ',' + run)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #set the needed variables
    threads = []

    for i in range (1, int(run)+1):
       process=threading.Thread(target=MyThread, args=(str(i), main_path, target_path, jiranum)) #### Is this defined right?
       process.start()
       threads.append(process)

       for process in threads:
          process.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be a simpler task with `concurrent.futures` but I like getting my hands dirty, so here we go. A few suggestions:

- I find classes as thread targets often complicate things, so if there's no compelling reason, keep it simple
- It's easier to use a `with` block to acquire and release a semaphore, and a regular semaphore usually suffices in that case
- 17 arguments can get messy; I would build a tuple of the arguments outside the call to `threading.Thread()` so it's easier to read, then unpack the tuple in the thread

This should work as a simple example; `os.system()` just echoes something and sleeps, so you can see the thread count is limited by the semaphore.

```
import os
import threading
from random import randint

threadLimiter = threading.Semaphore(10)

def run_config(*args):
    run, arg1, arg2 = args           # unpack the 17 args by name

    with threadLimiter:
        seconds = randint(2, 7)
        os.system(f"echo run {run}, args {arg1} {arg2} ; sleep {seconds}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    run = "20"          # I guess this is a string because of below?

    for i in range (1, int(run)+1):
        thr_args = (str(i), "arg1",
                    "arg2")           # put the 17 args here
        thr = threading.Thread(target=run_config, args=thr_args)
        thr.start()
        threads.append(thr)

    for thr in threads:
        thr.join()
```

Comment: this worked very well..  Only issue i am having is when it first spools up it does through an error that it cant create a thread but it does run all the processes.   thanks