# python how to set a thread limit?

Tags: python, multithreading

I was wondering how I could limit something like this too use only 10 threads at one time

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lines = line.rstrip("\n\r")
        t1 = Thread(target=Checker, args=("company"))
        t1.start()
```

Comment: Just monitor the threads alive and block until one of the threads exits if there are 10 of them or more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I limit the number of active threads in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787397/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-active-threads-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python thread pool similar to the multiprocessing Pool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit number of concurrent threads in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347228/how-to-limit-number-of-concurrent-threads-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Python's [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) with max_workers argument set to 10.

Something like this:`

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lines = line.rstrip("\n\r")
        pool.submit(Checker,"company")

pool.shutdown(wait=True)
```

The `pool` will automatically allocate threads as needed, limiting maximum number of allocation to 10. The first argument in `pool.submit()` is the function name, the arguments are simply passed as comma-separated values.

`pool.shutdown(wait=True)` waits for all threads to complete execution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and tell it that you want 10 threads.

```
def your_function_processing_one_line(line):
    pass  # your computations

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
    result = executor.map(your_function_processing_one_line, [line for line in f])
```

...and you will have all the results in `result`.

Comment: what if multiple params ?

Comment: This is also possible. Take a look at [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785226/pass-multiple-parameters-to-concurrent-futures-executor-map/6976772#6976772).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this nested loop to cap threads to a variable.
This code relies on a preset array of commands to process.
I have borrowed some elements from other answers for thread launch.

```
import os, sys, datetime, logging, thread, threading, time
from random import randint

# set number of threads
threadcount = 20

# alltests is an array of test data

numbertests = len(alltests)
testcounter = numbertests

# run tests
for test in alltests:
    # launch worker thread
    def worker():
        """thread worker function"""
        os.system(command)
        return
    threads = []
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    testcounter -= 1
    # cap the threads if over limit
    while threading.active_count() >= threadcount:
        threads = threading.active_count()
        string = "Excessive threads, pausing 5 secs - " + str(threads) 
        print (string)
        logging.info(string)
        time.sleep(5)

# monitor for threads winding down
while threading.active_count() != 1:
    threads = threading.active_count()
    string = "Active threads running - " + str(threads) 
    print (string)
    logging.info(string)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score -1):

(for both Python 2.6+ and Python 3)

Use the `threadPool` from `multiprocessing` module:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
```

The only thing is that it is not well documented...